# jQuery - ссылка на элемент

Tags: html, jquery

```
Может кто подскажет как на месте знаков вопросов указать ссылку того фото на которое я нажму, то есть элемента '$(this)'? Заранее спасибо!
$(".jw").click(function(){
        $(this) + $(".jw-gl").attr("src", "???");
    })

так же что бы было понятно, вот код ХТМЛ:
<h2>Mini galeria</h2>
                    <img src="jquery_pliki/jw1.png" width="100px" class="jw">
                    <img src="jquery_pliki/jw2.png" width="100px" class="jw">
                    <img src="jquery_pliki/jw3.png" width="100px" class="jw">
                    <img src="jquery_pliki/jw4.png" width="100px" class="jw">
                    <img src="jquery_pliki/jw5.png" width="100px" class="jw">
                    <img src="jquery_pliki/jw6.png" width="100px" class="jw">

                    <img src="jquery_pliki/jw1.png" width="200px" class="jw-gl">
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("src")`

Comment: Супер, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".jw").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Mini galeria</h2>
<img src="jquery_pliki/jw1.png" width="100px" class="jw">
<img src="jquery_pliki/jw2.png" width="100px" class="jw">
<img src="jquery_pliki/jw3.png" width="100px" class="jw">
<img src="jquery_pliki/jw4.png" width="100px" class="jw">
<img src="jquery_pliki/jw5.png" width="100px" class="jw">
<img src="jquery_pliki/jw6.png" width="100px" class="jw">

<img src="jquery_pliki/jw1.png" width="200px" class="jw-gl">
```